How to format SD as FAT32 on mac?
On Mac, using Disk Utility, there is only the option to format a SD card to exFAT.
I need to format it to FAT32 and probably try some older FAT file systems too.
The card is microSDXC. Similar questions on the site only provided the answer for other operating systems.

What kind of compatibility? MAC OS, Linux, Windows NATIVELY support exFAT

@RomeoNinov many embedded devices don't, not to mention Windowses before XP, seing that they explicitly mention "older FAT FSes".

@MarcusMüller, I have pretty good idea about this, but I have my doubts about the OP idea about compatibility. Moreover software for transfer images to SD may do this work too (if need)

Does this not work on your system? If not, pls let us know what system you have. It is run from the command line (i.e. Terminal.app or equivalent).
% diskutil list

# this will get you the information needed to complete the next command.
# you should get something like the following: 
#  NOTE the '/dev/disk4' is the important part:

/dev/disk4 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *31.9 GB    disk4
   1:       Microsoft Basic Data SOMENAME                31.7 GB    disk4s1

-- OR MAYBE THIS: --

/dev/disk4 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *63.9 GB    disk4
   1:               Windows_NTFS                         63.8 GB    disk4s1

Knowing where your SD card is located (/dev/disk4 in this case) allows you to format the drive/volume using the eraseDisk verb in diskutil:
% sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 SOMENAME GPT disk4
Started erase on disk4
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk4s2 as MS-DOS (FAT32) with name SOMENAME
512 bytes per physical sector
/dev/rdisk4s2: 61891008 sectors in 1934094 FAT32 clusters (16384 bytes/cluster)
bps=512 spc=32 res=32 nft=2 mid=0xf8 spt=32 hds=255 hid=411648 drv=0x80 bsec=61921280 bspf=15111 rdcl=2 infs=1 bkbs=6
Mounting disk
Finished erase on disk4

## To Confirm:  

% diskutil list disk4
/dev/disk4 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *31.9 GB    disk4
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk4s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data SOMENAME                31.7 GB    disk4s2

Pls note that GPT in the diskutil eraseDisk command means GUID Partition Table; if you prefer Master Boot Record, simply change the command above to the following:
% diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 SOMENAME MBR disk4

In your case (a microscope application), GPT vs MBR likely makes no difference.
